# File not received when sent with send_file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download, rails-5.1.6

I am sending file to client when they click on download in my application, however, the file don't get downloaded, by the client but the console indicates file been sent.

show.html.erb

```
<div class="col-10 music-detail">
    <hr/>
    <%= form_for :music, url: music_download_path do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :music_id, value: @music.id %>
        <%= f.submit :download, class:"download_btn "%>
        <span class="sownload_count"><%= @music.download_count%></span>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

MusicController.rb

```
def download
    music_id = params[:music][:music_id]

    music =  Music.find(music_id)

    if music.valid?
        music_rel_path = music.music_path

        music_file = gen_absolute_file_path music_rel_path

        send_file(music_file)

        download_count = music.download_count + 1

        music.update(download_count: download_count)

        redirect_to "/musics/#{music_id}"
    end
end
```

rails server console output indicating file sent

```
Started POST "/music_download" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-19 08:30:31 -0700
Processing by MusicsController#download as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"JmeNUnm7HgW8T55fALqQxN9a2v9MDKmJZCWsQ0MYfu3t1ETteowbAL  UMB0bf9Tu0zxFFORNj2TmOgnWW8EARIQ==", "music"=>{"music_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"download"}
Music Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "musics".* FROM "musics" WHERE "musics"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Sent file C:/Users/USER/Desktop/projects/filmz_legendary/public/secure/musics/samuel_samuel-samuel/all_of_my_days.mp3 (48.5ms)

(0.0ms)  begin transaction SQL (3.0ms)  UPDATE "musics" SET "download_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ?     WHERE "musics"."id" = ?  [["download_count", 7], ["updated_at", "2018-09-19 15:30:32.789257"], ["id", 2]]
(202.7ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/musics/2
Completed 302 Found in 274ms (ActiveRecord: 205.7ms)


Started GET "/musics/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-19 08:30:33 -0700
Processing by MusicsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
Music Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "musics".* FROM "musics" WHERE "musics"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Rendering musics/show.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered musics/show.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5278ms (Views: 5087.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I am using :

```
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]
ralis 5.1.6
```

Comment: Can you change your `send_file` line to look like this ? `send_file(music_file, :type => 'application/mp3', :disposition => 'attachment')`

Comment: It doesn't work either.